# Is Redux secure?

Tags: redux

I'm learning Redux and I can see people storing all kinds of information into the state and doing all kinds of different operations through reducers. But is Redux secure or is there any known vulnerabilities of using Redux? If there are then are there any best practices that I can follow to secure the state?

Comment: No, there are no known vulnerabilities of using Redux. It doesn't really make sense to analyze redux this way because it's just holding javascript data in memory. It's no more or less secure than Javascript itself.

Comment: Agree with Andy. If you handle data client-side with Redux that should not be handled client-side for security reasons, then this is not really Redux's fault.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna wait a while longer to see if there're any more answers while conducting more research by myself. If that's the case then I'm gonna remove this question.

Comment: It's probably a better question to ask if react has XSS vulnerabilities. The answer to that is well documented

Comment: Redux itself is just JS, so there are no additional security concerns beyond JS itself. But if you use `redux-persist` to persist to AsyncStorage, that's not secure. Consider using `react-native-keychain`

Comment: But if I save my token/userId in the server, then I have to leave it open to read for anyone. Otherwise I would need the token to get it. How is this going to work?

Comment: Just don't [connect](https://redux.js.org/usage/configuring-your-store#integrating-the-devtools-extension) Redux to *devltools* (via middlewere and only in **production**) so access to Redux is limited to internal code only and not exposed to the outside

Answer (score 12):

Maybe let's change the question - does keeping any data in the client side is safe? And answer is no. Any kind of secret data should never exist in the front side. State management system will not change the app security. Even if you have encapsulated state the data can be catched by watching the network and data coming to the browser or by traversing html because most of the data in the front side is just used in the view. So,  really any kind of data which gets to the browser should be considered as fully transparent and only the backend can really secure what is given and what not.

Answer (score 11):

Is it ***not a good idea*** to save passwords and sensitive information in your redux store. When you go into production, definitely turn off the [redux-devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) setting because if you don't then anyone can see your whole application state with the chrome extension (if you care about hiding your app state). You have to be especially careful if you are syncing your state to something like local storage as well. In general, send passwords or sensitive info right to the server in an encrypted fashion.

Comment: I would clarify the "In general, send passwords or sensitive info right to the server in an encrypted fashion." as this can be interpreted in multiple ways:

1. use SSL... Definitely yes!
2. encrypt the secret (for example hashing)... No, this does not protect you from replay attacts.