# Save user in store compromise the security of my application?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I'm using react with redux, and when the user logs in, I put the entire user object generated with the login in store. is it recommended to bring to the application any object user? const user = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,passwd)

```
export function* login(auth, action){
try{
    const {email, password} = action.user
    const user = yield auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwd)
    yield put(ActionCreator.signinSuccess(user))
}catch({message}){
    yield put(ActionCreator.signinFailure("Dind't have possible do login"))
}        
}
```

I use information like the token that comes in the user object to do authorization, the date of creation of the account and others .. so I keep all the object in the store of redux. Does this leave my system vulnerable?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer ([Is Redux secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538963/is-redux-secure)), is not a good idea to save sensitive data on the store.

If the data that you are saving will not compromise the application, it should be fine.
If not, then don't save on the store.

Comment: And about token? Of any form it will have to come through the net. Is it considered a sensitive data? In case a hacker can do anything knowing what my token is?

Comment: In that case, you can encrypt the token on each end of the app. With that, even if someone get the token, they can't use because is a encrypted data, not the real token value