# Preventing CSRF with an Express API and a React frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, csrf

I have been reading around CSRF for the past few days and feel like I have a good grasp on what it is and how to prevent it. I am building a small Express/React application that will have a secure admin area for updating the app content and I want it to be protected from CSRF.

I understand that it is common for the server to generate the CSRF token and then send it to the client along with the view (page) that has been requested (the token can then be hidden in a HTML form input tag). However, my Express API does not serve HTML, it is a REST API that only returns JSON data. The UI is built with React, running on a different port from the server.

My question is; Where do I securely store a token generated on the server?

For example, if I log in as admin by hitting '/api/login', generate a token, and send it back to the client in the API response, what should I do with it now?

The original plan was to use Redux to store the token but from reading this post [Is Redux secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538963/is-redux-secure), this does not sound ideal.

I considered using React env variables but have also read that these are exposed in the build.

Obviously localStorage is also a bad idea...

I am really struggling to find a solution to this problem using the tools I am implementing i.e. Express/React

Any help, links, advice, criticisms would be appreciate, I want to learn to build apps with security in mind

Comment: My preference for SPAs is to use a cookie-to-header CSRF token. Basically, as long as your frontend can be cookied by your backend, your frontend JS will be able to read that cookie and send it back as a separate header to the backend. Attackers won't be able to do this because they can't see the cookies. https://typeofnan.dev/using-cookie-based-csrf-tokens-for-your-single-page-application/

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks for you response. Based on your comment I just found an npm package called react-cookies, is that something you've used/would recommend?

Comment: I have never heard of it. I believe there is a backend node library called "csurf" that will create CSRF tokens and have an option to send as a cookie. Some fetch libraries (e.g., axios) will actually automagically find CSRF tokens in cookies and convert them to headers when sending back to the server

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, once I have found a way of doing it I'll write an answer to this question, if nobody answers it first. Thanks mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that it is common for the server to generate the CSRF token

The server needs to generate two CSRF tokens

> and then send it to the client along with the view (page) that has been requested (the token can then be hidden in a HTML form input tag).

One token is commonly sent as a cookie, another can be sent as HTTP header. It doesn't need to be sent inside HTML body as a HTML form input tag (or any other part of the body) though it can be sent this way.

> My question is; Where do I securely store a token generated on the server?

You don't have to store a token on the server. You can but you don't need to.

> The original plan was to use Redux to store the token

The Redux store is on the client, in browser's memory. In theory one React component (that extracts the second CSRF token from server response) can temporarily store the token in the store so that another React component can get it from there and put into the next request before it's sent to the server.

> Obviously localStorage is also a bad idea...

Yes

> Any help, links, advice, criticisms would be appreciate, I want to learn to build apps with security in mind

Links
With Express is very common to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf) middleware. The steps can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59549909).

Criticisms
This is strictly speaking off topic in the context of CSRF related Q/A, but ...

> The UI is built with React, running on a different port from the server.

That hints to the possibility of using `react-scripts` which start `webpack-dev-server`. It's fine for development, not good for deployment in production. However this is a separate topic, serving React app's build artifacts (.html file, script bundles) to webclients has nothing to do with CSRF attack and its mitigation.

> I want to learn to build apps with security in mind

Then you might consider using one webserver instead of two (frontend to serve React app and backend to serve API responses). Using one server results in production deployment which is not only less complex and costly, but also more secure because two servers have larger attack surface and with one server you don't need to weaken security by using CORS.

Comment: Thanks @winwin1 for that breakdown, that has given me plenty of food for thought. That last paragraph is especially interesting, there are so many tutorials that are ready to get you setup running a frontend server for React without ever mentioning the security implications. Your take is very refreshing and basically not mentioned in any of the resources I've used to learn React development. Cheers for the info